# Want to save .reg as regular text file ( not .reg file format )

Tags: regedit

Need to save some reg file key data into a text file I can then manipulate. Trouble is regedit only saves as a .reg file even if you tell it save as text file.  The resulting .reg file cannot be searched, grepped, or otherwise manipulated as text.
Ideas ?

Comment: Did you try changing the extension to .txt?

Comment: reg files are indeed txt files with a different extension. You should be able to `cat` and `grep` them without issue.

Comment: I agree with the above, but Windows Search DOES find text in a .REG file. They can also be opened, edited and changed with a text editor using Open With.

Comment: @SHawarden+ .reg files are **UTF-16** text. Many tools like grep don't handle that, at least not by default. But some things like notepad can _convert_ them to UTF-8, or to 'ANSI' (Microsoft's version) if the data contains only 8-bit (or ASCII = 7-bit) chars.

Comment: @Johm: Have you "told' indexing options that `.reg` files are plain text? `Control Panel (All Iems) > Indexing Options > Advanced > FIle Types`.  Select `.reg` & click `Index Properties and File Contents`.

Comment: To all: changing the file extension has no effect on the file format.  I'm searching the files with Linux, not Windows, Linux says the file format is  MPEG ADTS.   Saving as text from Notepad has no effect.  Making changes in "indexing options" has no effect on existing file format, its just a file search option.  I think this is another way Windows tries to keep its file type proprietary.   I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line: `START /W REGEDIT /E file.txt %REG_PATH%`

Credits to [@npocmaka](https://stackexchange.com/users/165169/npocmaka) for [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647093/12573645)

Answer (score 0):

in a .bat file (batch), use :

> regedit /e info.txt "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Windows.OpenWith"

replace **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Windows.OpenWith** with your key

Or, got to **control panel -> indexing options -> advanced**, then click on **more information about indexing**, to learn how to add a new extension to the search engine.